# OneToOneField related_query_name

Tags: django, orm

I have 2 models and one another is `OneToOneField` to another
Let me call `CaseIssue` and `ClosedCaseIssue` model

```
class CaseIssue(...):
   pass

class ClosedCaseIssue(...):
   case_issue = models.OneToOneField(CaseIssue, related_name='closed_case_issue', related_query_name='closed_case_issue', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

By using `related_query_name` I can search the `CaseIssue` which is still open. Open or Close determine by `ClosedCaseIssue` has been created and related to `CaseIssue`

This is correct number `CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue=None).count()`

This is my approach to get `Open CaseIssue`. But result is `1` which is wrong
`CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue=not None).count()`

**Question:**
What is the practical way to get `Open CaseIssue`?

Comment: `related_query_name` defaults to the value of `related_name` if set (ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write `not None`, since the result of `not None` is simply `True`. Indeed `not` checks the truthiness of the expression, and reverts it. So:

```
>>> not None
True
```

So you never pass `not None` itself to the Django ORM, only `True`, so that would mean that you actually check `.filter(closed_case_issue=True)`, so no we restrict the `closed_case_issue` to `True` (or `1`), and typically this will thus return at most 1 element.

But you can write a check for the *database* that checks if it is non `None`, by using the [**`isnull`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) lookup:

```
CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue__isnull=False).count()
```

Or in case you want to count the number of `CaseIssue`s for which there is a `ClosedCaseIssue`, you can use:

```
CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue__isnull=True).count()
```

This is equivalent to the `closed_case_issue=None` filter you have implemented.

You can also use this to filter, and thus retrieve `CaseIssue`s, for example:

```
open_issues = CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue__isnull=True)
closed_issues = CaseIssue.objects.filter(closed_case_issue__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using `is_null` and get frustrated.